# How can I output a file to download without saving it on the server first?

Tags: html, delphi, download, webbroker

Using Delphi XE3, DataSnap/WebBroker, HTML

I create and load a `TStringList` which I then save it to a file. I put the file location into the action of my HTML form to force a download. How can I do this without saving the file?

```
MyList := TStringList.Create;  (leaving out try/finally, etc.)
MyList.Add() ....
MyList.SaveToFile(MyFullFileName); 
MyList.Free;
```

Returning this HTML to `WebModuleDefaultHandler`:

```
<html><head /> 
  <body onload="document.FormOne.submit()"> 
    <form id="FormOne" name="FormOne" method="get" 
            action="MyFullFileName"> 
        <input type="submit" id="btSubmit1" name="btSubmit1"  /> 
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there some way I can send `MyList` without saving it first?

(Recipients are using standard browsers, not Delphi clients)

Comment: can you show how the HTML code should look like you are trying to get? Or are you looking for a way to answer a HTTP response with a plain text file which contains only the strings of the TStringList?

Comment: The latter.  My code above results in the Download Dialog, which asks you where to save the file (varies by browser).  I want to send the strings in a way that lets the user save them to a file, not display on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as a memory stream...

```
MyStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  MyList:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    MyList.Add() ...
    MyList.SaveToStream(MyStream);
  finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
  MyStream.Position:= 0;
  Response.ContentType:= 'text/html';
  Response.ContentStream:= MyStream;
finally
  MyStream.Free;
end;
```

When a request comes into the server from the client, you need to pass the stream `MyStream` back as the Response `ContentStream` field. Don't forget to always set streams back to 0 before doing anything with them!

Or, alternatively, you could also do it using the String List's `Text` property. Like so...

```
  MyList:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    MyList.Add('<html>');
    MyList.Add('<heading/>');
    MyList.Add('<body>DataSnap Server</body>');
    MyList.Add('</html>');
    Response.ContentType:= 'text/plain';
    Response.Content:= MyList.Text;
  finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
```

Typically using streams is best when you need to load/save/host raw files, such as images. It can be very convenient to draw to a canvas, convert that canvas to a JPG image, and save it as a Stream instead of a File. Then, pass it as `Response.ContentStream`. Therefore, I've gotten more used to using streams because it's a more standard way of returning content.

PS - If you'd like this file to be able to show as plain text, then use `ContentType` of `text/plain`, or if you'd like any type of file to be downloaded as a file like `test.txt` then you can use `application/octet-stream` for `ContentType`.

Comment: From Debby:  The MyStream example is on target, but the crux of the issue, for me, is the part you left out:  //Send MyStream

How do I send it?   My HTML currently uses 

<form ... method="get" action="MyFullFileName">

Can I just substitute "MyStream" for "MyFullFileName"?

Comment: I didn't understand "how to send" as the question, I understood "send without saving to file" as the question, assuming you know how to send it. If you don't know how to send it, you need to be more specific with what exactly you're intending to use to send it - an HTTP server cannot send anything to a client, only the client can ask the server for data. One-way connections.

Comment: I know how to create a .txt file and send/force-download it to a browser.  Better question:  How can I achieve the same result without leaving a file on the hard drive?  Answer:  Using a stream is a good start.  But the main point is to have data end up on the hard drive of the user.  I had already tried TStringStream, but did not know how to send it.  So either I need to learn how to get Delphi/WebBroker to return a stream that looks like a file, or I need some other structure and the method for sending that structure.  The browser requires HTML, so yes, HTML is part of the answer.

Comment: I updated my answer and code and hope that should be all you need.

Comment: This is great!  Exactly what I needed.  application/octet-stream is the best part at the moment, but I have stashed the TStream details for future use.  I really appreciate your hanging in there until I got the question right.  Do I need to do something on this site to give you proper credit for getting the right answer?

Comment: Whoops, just fixed a dumb mistake of mine :D

Comment: Wait a second, if I remember right, streams aren't supposed to be free'd in this manner... It should be created, passed into `ContentStream`, and then the web server will do the rest to free it when it's done with it...